# when build gazebo ,how to assign it to include ogre 1.8

Tags: ros, gazebo, ogre, build-from-source, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because I had installed ogre1.8,
then, I installed ogre1.9 again.

Now ,when I build gazebo 2.0

It comes to an error

> Bad Ogre3d version: gazebo using 1.9.0
> ogre version has known bugs in runtime
> (issue #996). Please use 1.7 or 1.8
> series

I don't know how to  assign gazebo  ogre 1.8

I tried to use cmake-gui to find if there is a name such as "ogre" "path"

but I could not find such name like that.

I also tried to enter:

> export OGRE_HOME=/usr/local/ogre1.8

but it still didn't work

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166991/when-build-gazebo-,how-to-assign-it-to-include-ogre-1.8/) by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/18171/zheng-yo-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First build and install the Ogre version you want (1.8 in this case). You can use cmake-gui to specify the install locations. Or if you don't, it will probably go into /usr/lib.

Then make sure the you have the .pc files for Ogre (these files can be used to tell gazebo through cmake modules where to find the Ogre installation). And finally make sure the location of these .pc files is included in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH env variable or set it during your cmake call.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0